# Express Integer as Sum of Two Squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a general method to expressing integers as the sum of two squares or do you just need to be good with numbers? For example, consider the following problem:

> Express 605 as the sum of two squares

Now I believe that a solution to this problem exists because $605 = 5 \cdot  11^2$ and $11 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ which appears an even number of times and $11$ is the only number in the prime factorization that is congruent to $3 \pmod 4$.

So looking at this problem, what are the first steps that you should take to try and solve this problem? Is there a quick way to go about this?

Comment: Note that $5$ can be written as a sum of two squares (that are easy to find) and that $11^2$ is a square.

Comment: At least you have nearly given the solution : $605 = 5 . 11 ^ 2$ so $605 = 11^2 + (2.11)^2$...

Comment: Nice question and well explained by an example +1

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie, just a little more and that comments of yours could be a very good answer, at least in some wide spectrum of cases.

Comment: Just to make this discussion thread more interesting.. Any natural number can be represented as the sum of four integer squares [Lagrange's four-square theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but from memory something which it turns out is called the *Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity* or occasionally *Diophantus identity* (used constructively in the proof of the result of Fermat) might be useful: see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity).

$$\left(a^2 + b^2\right)\left(c^2 + d^2\right) = \left(ac-bd\right)^2 + \left(ad+bc\right)^2 
                                             = \left(ac+bd\right)^2 + \left(ad-bc\right)^2$$

This allows you to strip off factors one at a time.

Where you have squares in the factorization, as in the $5\cdot 11^2$ case, note that the square can be factored out as $(p^2+q^2)m^2 = (pm)^2 + (qm)^2$

Comment: For a natural number $n$ and a prime number $p$ let $\deg_p n$ be a maximal integer number $l$ such that $p^l|n$. Then I suppose that there is an expression of $n$ as a sum of two squares (which is obtainable by the above method) iff $\deg_p$ is even for each prime $p$ of the form $4k+1$.

Comment: I think you can restrict the number of things you have to try but this amounts to experimentation. (Judging by the proofs at http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat's_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares ) I'll leave it to others to translate these into algorithms, but finding (10,9) in this case I would do by inspection.

Comment: @Alex Your last sentence should be $4k+3$.

Comment: Yes, it was a mispint. Thanks.