# Express Integer as Sum of Four Squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is kind of a follow-up to the question I posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366421/express-integer-as-sum-of-two-squares) about expressing integers as the sum of two squares. Is there a similar general method for expressing integers as the sum of four squares? I believe the [Lagrange's Four-Square Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) states that all positive integers are expressible as the sum of four squares of integers, but how do you find these numbers. As an example consider the value $1638$. How can we find the four squares?

Comment: See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/68501/755, http://stackoverflow.com/q/41524508/781723, http://mathoverflow.net/q/259152/37212, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/366673/14578, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/483101/14578, http://mathoverflow.net/q/110239/37212.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Similar to the [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci two-square identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity). Euler has a [four square identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_four-square_identity) which involves the sum of 4 squares:

$$(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2+a_4^2)(b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2+b_4^2) =\\ 
\quad(a_1b_1 - a_2b_2 - a_3b_3 - a_4b_4)^2 + (a_1b_2+a_2b_1+a_3b_4-a_4b_3)^2
+(a_1b_3 - a_2b_4 + a_3b_1 + a_4b_2)^2 + (a_1b_4 + a_2b_3 - a_3b_2 + a_4b_1)^2$$

Factor $1638$ as products of any small factors you know how to represent as sum of 4 squares. Repeat apply the formula will allow you to represent $1638$ itself as sum of 4 squares.

For example, let's say we have factored $1638$ as $2\cdot 3^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 13$, we have:

$$\begin{align}
  & 2\cdot 3^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 13\\ 
= & (1^2+1^2+0^2+0^2)(1^2+1^2+1^2+0^2)^2(2^2+1^2+1^2+1^2)(3^2+2^2+0^2+0^2)\\
= & (0^2 + 2^2 + 1^2 + 1^2)(1^2+1^2+1^2+0^2)(2^2+1^2+1^2+1^2)(3^2+2^2+0^2+0^2)\\
= & ((-3)^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + 2^2)(2^2+1^2+1^2+1^2)(3^2+2^2+0^2+0^2)\\
= & ((-11)^2+(-1)^2+2^2 + 0^2)(3^2+2^2+0^2+0^2)\\
= & ((-31)^2 + (-25)^2 + 6^2 + 4^2)\\
\end{align}$$

This give you a non-trivial representation of $1638$ as $31^2 + 25^2 + 6^2 + 4^2$.

In general, there are many representations of a number as a sum of 4 squares.
There is a theorem:

> The total number of representations of a positive integer $n$ as the
>   sum of four squares, representations that differ only in order and sign
>   being counted as distinct, is eight times the sum of the divisors of
>   $n$ that are not multiple of $4$.

The above representation is only $1$ out of $8 \sum_{d\mid 1638, 4 \nmid d} d = 34944$
ways of representing $1638$ as sum of 4 squares.

Answer (score 3):

Just as the Gaussian integers are a modern method to prove every prime not congruent to $3$ (mod $4$) is a sum of two squares ( since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a Euclidean domain), a similar method works for the so-called Hurwitz quaternions $\mathbb{H} = \{ \frac{a+bi + cj +dk}{2}: a,b,c,d \in  \mathbb{Z}, a \equiv b \equiv c \equiv d ({\rm mod} 2) \}$.$  \mathbb{H}$ is not a commutative ring, but behaves sufficiently like a Euclidean ring that a similar proof shows that every prime $p$ is a sum of $4$ integer squares. A full proof can be found in I.N. Herstein's "Topics in Algebra", but here is an outline: given any odd prime $p \in \mathbb{N}$, we can express $-1$ as a sum of two squares in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. This means that there are integers $a,b$ such that $p |(a^{2}+b^{2}+1).$ This means that $p$ is not an irreducible element in $\mathbb{H}$, and this leads to the fact that $p = x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+w^{2}$ for integers $x,y,z,w$. Once we know that every prime has such an expression, it follows (as noted in other answers and comments) that every positive integer is a sum of $4$ integer squares. However, it should be noted that, in practice, this may not be the most efficient way to express a given positive integer as a sum of $4$ integer squares.

Answer (score 2):

$1638=2\cdot3^2\cdot7\cdot13=(1^2+1^2)3^2(2^2+1^2+1^2+1^2)(3^2+2^2)$  Now use your technique for taking the product of two sums of two squares to a sum of two squares.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Using the same condition as your previous question. 
If you can express the two numbers which add up to 1638 as a sum of two squares. You are through.:)