# Decomposition into three squares

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, sums-of-squares

Doing a coding assignment. And it's basically having a user enter $n$. Then I need to provide (If it exists) $$n = x^2 + y^2 + z^2.$$

Not really sure how to approach this. Any ideas?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_three-square_theorem

Comment: This is very cool result, Lab!

Comment: Exactly what Im looking for! But Im having a bit of trouble with the wording. Any chance you can give me a breif synopsis thats less proofy?

Comment: I discuss Rabin and Shallit's paper on good randomized algorithms for this problem [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/651425/3111), and for the related topic of how many ways $n$ might be expressed as the sum of three squares, see [this Answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/643830/3111).

Comment: Related post on MathOverflow: [Efficient computation of integer representation as a sum of three squares](https://mathoverflow.net/q/104322#325596)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So following from Lab's link we have $$n=x^2+y^2+z^2\iff n\ne4^a(8b+7)$$
Therefore to test we divide by 4 as much as possible at least once. Then subtract 7 and test if it is divisible by 8. If the divisibilities are true then you have a number that can't be represented as such.

---

Algorithm

1. Check divisibility by 4. If it is not divisible then $n$ is such a number.
2. Keep dividing by 4 until it is no longer divisible.
3. Subtract 7.
4. Check divisibility by 8. If it is divisible then $n$ is not such a number else $n$ is such a number.

Comment: this is incorrect in your algorithm step 1; I admit, I am having a little trouble following your wording. However, in $4^a (8 b + 7)$ the bounds would be $a \geq 0, b \geq 0.$ In particular, $7$ and $15$ are not sums of three squares, easy to confirm with pencil and paper.

Comment: @WillJagy Unfortunately what I wrote was not what I was thinking. Let me fix this.

Comment: your profile mentions programming, i suggest you write a simple triple loop program to find the three-square-sums up to, say, $250,$ and print out in order, 10 such numbers per line I guess. After that write a second program for your "algorithm" above, see if you can get the two lists to agree. The nice thing about elementary number theory is that we can write programs and look for patterns in the output. Wow, Everton 3, Chelsea 4, minute 76

Comment: @WillJagy My answer may not be the best however the OP has accepted it so they must be happy with the information given. I am not too interested in perusing an algorithm.

Comment: sorry to hear that