# Can You Generate the Number of Lattice Points on a Sphere using Hamiltonian Integers? (Lattice-Points)

Tags: combinatorics

**Can You Find the Number of Lattice Points on a Sphere by Using Hamiltonian Integers?**

What prompted me to ask this question was this video on YouTube called "Finding Pi in Prime Regularities".

Comment: is sqr(N) means $\sqrt{N}$?

Comment: Yes. It means the square root of n

Comment: Please [read this page first](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) before you post a question next time.... actually do it now and try to edit this post ... also write `$\sqrt{x}$` instead of sqr(x)... also [see here for How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Comment: Related: [Does this equation have positive integer solutions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643754/does-this-equation-have-positive-integer-solutions) and [Rabin and Shallit algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483101/rabin-and-shallit-algorithm).  It is a bit unclear what your purpose is in introducing the Gaussian integers "including the imaginary unit $j$", since the Gaussian integers have only one real and one imaginary axis.  Perhaps [Hamiltonian integers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianInteger.html) are more suited here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the radius is $r$,
the equation of the sphere is
$x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2$.

If $r = \sqrt{N}$,
this becomes
$x^2+y^2+z^2 = N$.

Therefore
you are looking for
the number of ways
$N$ can be represented as
the sum of 3 squares.

Since there are 8 octants
(for all possible signs
of $x, y, z$),
the representations
for non-zero $x, y, z$
are counted up to 8 times.

Look up
"sums of three squares".

For a more advanced discussion,
see
www.ams.org/tran/1951-071-01/S0002-9947-1951-0042438-4/S0002-9947-1951-0042438-4.pdf
("ON THE REPRESENTATIONS OF A NUMBER AS THE
SUM OF THREE SQUARES"
BY
PAUL T. BATEMAN)

Comment: See also [this OEIS entry](http://oeis.org/A063691).

Comment: Quite useful. Thanks,