# Show that $ \# \{ (a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{Z}^4 : a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = m\} \asymp m $

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sums-of-squares

I found this result mentioned in passing in a number theory paper.  It looks almost self-evident:

$$ \# \{ (a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{Z}^4 : a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2  = m\} \asymp m $$

It is stated without proof.  It looks almost like the 4-squares theorem in fact that number is $r_4(m)$ which is  [A000118](https://oeis.org/A000118)

[image]

This plot looks possibly linear, but with a bunch of noise.  It doesn't look obvious.

- Valentin Blomer, Anke Pohl [The sup-norm problem for the Siegel modular space of rank two](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.4635) arXiv:1402.4635

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366673/express-integer-as-sum-of-four-squares

Comment: Where exactly in the paper is this mentioned? Do you mean the number of $4\times 4$-matrices on page $17$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Top of page 17 in this paper of Blomer and Pohl.   Those matrices are in bijection with solutions to the 4-squares equation right? These well-known results, they mention in passing, are always news to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Jacobi's four-square theorem we have
$$
r_4(n)​=\begin{cases}​8\sum\limits_{m|n}​m&​\text{if }​n\text{ is odd}​\\[12pt]​
24\sum\limits_{\begin{smallmatrix}​ m|n \\ m\text{ odd}​ \end{smallmatrix}​}​m&​\text{if }​n\text{ is even}​.
\end{cases}​​
$$
For $n=p$ prime this gives, for example, $r_4(p)=8(p+1)\asymp p$. In general, the asymptotic growth rate of $\sigma(n)=\sum_{m\mid n}m$  can be expressed by:
$$
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n\,\log \log n}=e^\gamma.
$$
The behaviour of the sigma function is very irregular, as your plots also show.

Comment: Doesn't that show $r_4(m) \asymp m \, \log \log m$ ?  It's good, but there's a little bit of extra room.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is what it is. Perhaps the sign $\asymp$ was interpreted a bit more generous.