# How do I find two integers - $x$ and $y$ - whose values satisfy the expression $x^2 + y^2 = z$, where $z$ is a perfect square?

Tags: arithmetic

I watched a YouTube video of an episode of *Who Wants To Be A Millionaire?*, in which a contestant was presented with a list of perfect squares. He was asked to choose the number that was also the sum of two smaller perfect squares. This video got me wondering if there is a way to find the correct answer choice. I thought he could maybe try each answer choice and see if there exists two integers, the sums of which add up to the chosen number.

Pythagorean triples come to mind.

Comment: A quick Google search reveals the following rather nice webpage: http://wims.unice.fr/wims/en_tool~number~twosquares.en.html. It allows you to enter an integer and receive back all of its decompositions into integer squares. Moreover, the 'explanations' link contained there gives a nice description of the relevant mathematics. Edit: In fact, Wikipedia has an entire page for this problem: [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares).

Comment: Can you link to the video?

Comment: We are given a perfect square $m^2$. This can be written as a sum of two non-zero squares if and only if $m$ is divisible by a prime of the form $4k+1$. This is a fairly straightforward criterion to apply if $m$ is not large. For example $m=25$ yes, $26$ yes, $27$ no, $28$ no, $29$ yes, $30$ yes.

Comment: 30 doesn't work.

Comment: @vgmath yes it does 30 forms a Pythagorean Triple with 18 and 24

$18^2 + 24^2 = 324 + 576 = 900 = 30^2$

Comment: If $z$ is a perfect square --- say, $z=r^2$  --- then just take $x=r$ and $y=0$. You know, zero is an integer.

Comment: @Ben: I thought it talks about $30$, not $30^2.$, sorry.

Comment: @ Gerry: Thanks for reminding that zero is an integer! But, it asks for two smaller perfect squares, so you're not allowed to use zero.

Comment: It $z$ is a perfect square, you are just asking about Pythagorean triples !

Comment: Look at the first two pages of Marcus' book "Number Fields": you'll find a complete answer.

Comment: @Joe Would you mind posting an excerpt or two from the book?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Express Integer as Sum of Two Squares](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366421/express-integer-as-sum-of-two-squares)

Answer (score 4):

**Note: Definitions for certain terms are posted below.**

It is quite easy if you use the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\text{i}]$ of Gaussian integers.  For $w\in\mathbb{Z}[\text{i}]$, write $\bar{w}$ for the complex conjugate of $w$.  Factorize $z\in \mathbb{N}$ as a product of primes $$z=2^mp_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}\cdots p_k^{r_k}q_1^{s_1}q_2^{s_2}\cdots q_l^{s_l}$$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, where the $p_i$'s and the $q_j$'s are positive odd primes such that $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and $q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_l\equiv -1\pmod{4}$.  It is well known that $z$ is a sum of two square if and only if each of the $s_j$'s is even.  From now on, we assume that $s_j$ is even for every $j=1,2,\ldots,l$.

For $i=1,2,\ldots,k$, $p_i$ can be factorized into the product $\pi_i\bar{\pi}_i$, where $\pi_i\in\mathbb{Z}[\text{i}]$ is a Gaussian prime.  Also, $2=(1+\text{i})(1-\text{i})$.  Hence, you can pick $\mu_i\in\left\{0,1,\ldots,r_i\right\}$ for each $i=1,2,\ldots,k$ and write $$z=\left((1+\text{i})^m\,\prod_{i=1}^k \pi_i^{\mu_i}\bar{\pi}_i^{r_i-\mu_i}\,\prod_{j=1}^l q_j^{s_j/2}\right)\left((1-\text{i})^m\,\prod_{i=1}^k \bar{\pi}_i^{\mu_i}\pi_i^{r_i-\mu_i}\,\prod_{j=1}^l q_j^{s_j/2}\right)\,.$$  Hence, if $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ are such that $$x+y\text{i}=u\,(1+\text{i})^m\,\prod_{i=1}^k \pi_i^{\mu_i}\bar{\pi}_i^{r_i-\mu_i}\,\prod_{j=1}^l q_j^{s_j/2}\,,$$ where $u\in\{-1,+1,-\text{i},+\text{i}\}$, then $x-y\text{i}=\bar{u}\,(1-\text{i})^m\,\prod_{i=1}^k \bar{\pi}_i^{\mu_i}{\pi}_i^{r_i-\mu_i}\,\prod_{j=1}^l q_j^{s_j/2}$ and 
$$z=(x+y\text{i})(x-y\text{i})=x^2+y^2\,.$$

It can be shown that there are $4\prod_{i=1}^k\left(r_i+1\right)$ ways to find $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $x^2+y^2=z$.  Since there are $4$ ways to choose $u$ and, for $i=1,2,\ldots,k$, there are $r_i+1$ ways to choose $\mu_i$, we have found all possible pairs $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $x^2+y^2=z$.  If signs and ordering of $x,y$ are ignored, there are exactly $\left\lceil\frac{1}{2}\prod_{i=1}^k\left(r_i+1\right)\right\rceil$ possible pairs. If you want to exclude the case where $x$ or $y$ may be zero, then there are two cases:

(1) All $r_i$'s are even: there are $\frac12\left(\prod_{i=1}^k\left(r_i+1\right)-(-1)^m\right)$ pairs of nonzero $x,y$, up to signs and order;

(2) At least one of the $r_i$'s is odd: there are $\frac{1}{2}\prod_{i=1}^k\left(r_i+1\right)$ pairs of nonzero $x,y$, up to signs and order.

For example, let $z:=90=2\cdot 5\cdot 3^2$, with $2=(1+\text{i})(1-\text{i})$ and $5=(2+\text{i})(2-\text{i})$.  Hence, we can take $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x+y\text{i}=(1+\text{i})\cdot (2+\text{i})\cdot 3=3+9\text{i}$, or $(x,y)=(3,9)$.  In fact, there are $8$ ways to write $z=90$ as a sum of two squares; i.e., $(\pm3,\pm9)$ and $(\pm9,\pm3)$ are all possible values of $(x,y)$ (only one pair---$(x,y)=(3,9)$---if sings and ordering are ignored).  Another example is $z:=50$.  There are $12$ ways to write $z$ as a sum of two squares; i.e., $(\pm5,\pm5)$, $(\pm1,\pm7)$, and $(\pm7,\pm1)$ are all possible values of $(x,y)$ (only two pairs---$(x,y)=(5,5)$ and $(x,y)=(1,7)$---if signs and ordering are ignored).

In the case where $z=t^2$ for some $t\in\mathbb{N}$, the situation is not changed at all.  You still need to factorize $z$ as above.  For example, if $z=13^2\cdot 17^2\cdot 19^2$, you notice that $13=(3+2\text{i})(3-2\text{i})$ and $17=(4+\text{i})(4-\text{i})$. So, you can take $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x+y\text{i}=(3+2\text{i})\cdot(4+\text{i})\cdot 19=19(10+11\text{i})$, or $(x,y)=(10\cdot 19,11\cdot 19)$.  Indeed, there are $36$ possible solutions $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ to $x^2+y^2=z$, and, up to signs and order, there are $5$ of them: $(10\cdot 19,11\cdot 19)$, $(5\cdot 19,14\cdot 19)$, $(1\cdot 13\cdot 19,4\cdot 13\cdot 19)$, $(2\cdot 17\cdot 19,3\cdot 17\cdot 19)$, and $(0,13\cdot 17\cdot 19)$.

**P.S.**  If you are asking how to factorize an integer prime $p\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ into a product $\pi\bar{\pi}$ of conjugate Gaussian primes $\pi$ and $\bar{\pi}$, then you first need to solve for $t^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ (you can, in fact, take $t:=\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!$, but it is probably easier to search for $t\in\left\{1,2,\ldots,\frac{p-1}{2}\right\}$ directly, when $p$ is large).  The ring $\mathbb{Z}[\text{i}]$ has a division algorithm.  Therefore, you can define a Euclidean algorithm in $\mathbb{Z}[\text{i}]$.  Then, you take $\pi$ to be a greatest common divisor of $p$ and $t+\text{i}$.

For example, if $p=29$, we take $t:=12 \equiv \left(\frac{29-1}{2}\right)!\pmod{29}$.  Perform the Euclidean algorithm to get $p=(t+\text{i})\cdot 2+(5-2\text{i})$ and $t+\text{i}=(5-2\text{i})\cdot(2+\text{i})+0$, from which we conclude that $5-2\text{i}$ is a greatest common divisor of $p$ and $t+\text{i}$.  Hence, $\pi$ can be taken to be $5-2\text{i}$.  Note that $p=\pi\bar{\pi}$, as desired.  For more information, see the notes by Keith Conrad below.

**Definitions**

Factorize: "resolve or be resolvable into factors." [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Afactorize)

Gaussian integer: "a complex number whose real and imaginary parts are both integers" [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer)

**Reference**

http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/Zinotes.pdf

Comment: If possible, will you please "dumb it down" a little? Thanks.