# Integer solutions for $x^2+y^2=208$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Which steps I can follow to find the integer solutions for the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 208$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A positive integer is the sum of two squares iff primes $\equiv 3\pmod 4$ (following the Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares) of its factorization are raised to even exponents.

$$208=2^4\cdot 13$$

So, $208$ meets the condition.

Now, $13=3^2+2^2$, so $208=4^2(3^2+2^2)=12^2+8^2$

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me what can I study to learn how to do this? I did not studied this yet.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341756/how-do-i-find-two-integers-x-and-y-whose-values-satisfy-the-expression/1341774#1341774

Comment: I studied this in my first course of my grade in Maths.

Comment: @MateusCoutinhoMarim, many number theory textbooks have these results. One book is Hardy and Wright's Introduction to the Theory of Numbers. That may be a bit dense though. There is also Strayer's Elementary Number Theory, which is fairly easy to read.

Answer (score 4):

Since $208$ is a relatively small number, it is not too hard to check $208-x^2$ for all numbers $0\leq x\leq 14$ to see if the answer is a square number. The negatives of whatever solutions you find are also solutions.

Answer (score 2):

This represents a circle centered at the origin of radius $\sqrt{208}$.  You only need to check integer $x$-coordinates between $-14$ and $14$.