# Algorithm for factoring large decomposable primes into Gaussian primes

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers

Given a prime $p$ (with residual 1 modulo 4) what is the most efficient algorithm for computing its Gaussian prime factors, assuming $p$ could be large (i.e. perhaps more than 100 bits).  Equivalently, is there a fast algorithm for finding the pair of positive integers $(a,b)$ for which $a^2 + b^2 = p$ that is significantly faster than trial and error?

Answer (score 2):

After a little research I believe I have discovered the solution to this problem myself. The key is to solve $t^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, which can be efficiently solved using Tonelli-Shanks (among other algorithms).  Then $a+bi = \gcd(t+i,p)$, which is easily solved using Euclid's algorithm.

[see related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341756/how-do-i-find-two-integers-x-and-y-whose-values-satisfy-the-expression/1341774#1341774)